# Работа с List<T> В C#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток! Имеется массив `List<Button>`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне получить индекс элемента `button11` из массива по его имени? Видимо надо как то использовать `List<T>.FindIndex - метод (Predicate<T>)`, но что-то не могу разобраться.

Comment: стоит посмотреть [справку по этому методу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy, именно там и смотрел) Я Java учу, но начал изучать Unity, поэтому некоторые моменты сложноваты. Синтаксис иногда сильно отличается.

Comment: Так там как раз приведен пример использования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `FindIndex()` в качестве параметра принимает делегат типа `Predicate<T>`. Это значит, что он принимает методы, у которых есть один параметр типа `T` и которые возвращают значение `bool`. Поскольку вам список содержит кнопки, ваш метод будет выглядеть так:

```
private string _buttonName;

...

private bool IsButtonFound(Button button)
{
    return button.Name == _buttonName;
}
```

А использовать его нужно так:

```
_buttonName = "...";
int index = list.FindIndex(IsButtonFound);
```

Если воспользоваться [анонимными методами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb882516.aspx), то можно обойтись и без поля `_buttonName`:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(b => b.Name == "...");
```

Если индекс вам нужен для того, чтобы потом получить эту самую кнопку, то можно сразу попробовать получить ее с помощью метода расширения [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj2jbDlueTOAhWFOxQKHZg9BfIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fru-ru%2Flibrary%2Fbb340482(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEC8Wxz8F0bs4W2rUeQ0cSXLgS0Sg&sig2=Jwid6C03H1l8Tj_yYAVbMA&bvm=bv.131286987,d.d24):

```
using System.Linq;

...

var button = list.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "...");
if (button != null)
{
    // кнопка найдена
}
```

P.S. И `List<T>` -- это таки не [массив](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiX0sPcueTOAhUPsBQKHU75DvkQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%259C%25D0%25B0%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2_(%25D0%25BF%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5)&usg=AFQjCNEVOIuwXkEVIHVgxaelCdpmf2VOVA&sig2=YI1ieugDMIYsnafyTvVwTg&bvm=bv.131286987,d.d24), а [список](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNsunRueTOAhWCxxQKHQS2AvsQFgg4MAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A1%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA_(%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%2584%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0)&usg=AFQjCNF1eR8PSF3vKGdGmXMCcXCA7Auk5Q&sig2=VnTjjIpo05WbpeMsYuahqA).

Answer (score 2):

А не проще ли сделать так:

```
Button btn = btn_list.First(n => n.Name == "button11"); // btn_list - ваш List<Button>
```